# How to I convert a stackexchange question into a pdf file?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I want to save a question I wrote into a nice pdf file but I have no idea of how to go about it. Surely there is a simple way? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: okay I have accidentally make that question on an unregistered but want to edit the question. How do I access it or transfer it to my account? I really am an idiot

Comment: @idiot2.0: The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Simplest possible: Take screenshots of the question. Using a graphics program such as GIMP, knit them into one image. Export the image as PDF. It will still be an image (not text). Second simplest possible: Copy the text into a word processor (such as Libre Office). Export as PDF.